# Rails 3 - ActiveRecord and reverse sort

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, rails-activerecord

I have following data in database:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And I would like to get to output this:

```
3
4
5
```

I need it to print in the view:

```
<%car.colors.limit(3).order('created_at ASC').each do |color|%>
  ...
```

I know that exists **reverse_order**, but exist something like **reverse sort**?

(I know that is possible to load the data into an array and then go through the array, but this way is not very efficient)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about just doing

```
<%car.colors.limit(3).order('created_at DESC').reverse.each do |color|%>
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter like to tell me what I've got wrong?

Comment: This method reverses the data after it has been retrieve from the database.  The answer from JellicleCat uses the database to sort it.

Comment: @MattScilipoti - but it gives the wrong answer. The OP wants (the first three in descending order), printed in ascending order. You'll note that I also use the database to perform the descending order, but I can't see how to use the DB to get it back into ascending order for display.

Answer (score 21):

For Rails 4:

```
[Model].order(column: :desc)
```

For Rails 3:

```
[Model].order("<column> DESC")
```

For Rails 2:

```
[Model].all(:order => "<column> DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

**One line Solution**

in your controller use:

```
class Api::ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts =  Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4).order(id: :desc)
    render :json => @posts.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
  end

end
```